# DataFrame changing the DataType by using "astype"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got the following problem:

I have a Dataframe, where i would like to set the decimals to a fixed width,
and if i change the "columnstyle" by using "apply{}" it works perfectly, but if i export this dataframe as a *.txt i become an error with an other program, where i would like to import this Dataset. If i do the change via *.astype(float) the programm is able to import the Dataset, but get problemes with the tabulators and the size of each value.

[image]

Is there a way to set each value to a fixed size by using *.astype()?

For Example the Column "F [HZ]" Should look like: 30.00, 10.78, 10.90

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using pd.to_csv to save it as a text file. In this you can use it as below to save the floating numbers with a fixed width:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'F[HZ]': [30, 10.78, 10.9025], 'T[C]':[-50, -50, -50]})
df.to_csv('outfile.txt', float_format='%.2f')
```

Additionally you can also import in others and use astype to round it to two decimal place with below code:

```
df['F[HZ]'] = df['F[HZ]'].astype(float).round(2)
```

And if you do not want the T[C] as float then you can set it to integer type as below:

```
df['T[C]'] = df['T[C]'].astype(int)
```

And to show the datatype of different columns you can use the below print  statement:

```
print(df.info())
```

Comment: yeah this works, BUT this way i become an decimal to my temperature and the program returns an error. xD i hate this program... its really buggy...

Answer (score 0):

you can set float format in pandas

df

```
    name    max
0   a   1
1   b   2
2   c   2
3   d   4
4   e   1



df['max'].apply('{:.2f}'.format)
```

Out:

```
0   1.00
1   2.00
2   2.00
3   4.00
4   1.00
```

Comment: Thats just the "display" option and not a permanent change. :-/

Comment: can you try this "df['max'].apply('{:.2f}'.format)"   @NilsKohlmey

Comment: "Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'" :-/

Comment: plz apply that before convertion of string, it worked for me well, you might have changed int or float values to string before .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i did it this way and it works:

```
COLUMNS = {0:'F [HZ]', 1:'T [°C]', 2:"""G'""", 
               3:"""G''""", 4:"""|G|""", 5:'DELTA_D'}

for ii in range(len(COLUMNS)):

    if COLUMNS[ii] == 'T [°C]':

        df[COLUMNS[ii]] = df[COLUMNS[ii]].astype(int)

    else:

        df[COLUMNS[ii]] = df[COLUMNS[ii]].astype(float).apply('{:.2f}'.format)
```

Thanks everyone for help! :)